# Is There a Tool to Generate Database schema from XML Schema?

Tags: sql-server, xsd

I am looking to generate a MSSQL schema from an excising industry standard xsd file.  Any suggestions on which Tool to use?  I have played with XMLspy but I need a little more flexibility in the data type mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have likely already tried this, but I've used the MS XML Bulk Load for this before.

Couple of useful related articles:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316005

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa225763(SQL.80).aspx