# Tool or framwork to persist XML to relational tables?

Tags: xml, xsd, relational-database

I am working with the Yahoo! Developer API and there are a lot of responses that I would like to persist to relational tables (SQL Server) so that I can query it later (and over time). Is there a tool or framework that will automatically script these tables for me from sample XML or do I have to build it manually?

Answer (score 0):

XML is a type in MSSQL Server 2008 (I am assuming you're using this version).  You can store the XML directly in a column and then use XPATH http://www.w3schools.com/xpath or XQUERY /xquery to mine the data later.  This will prevent the pain that you would likely encounter if the schema or XSD for the XML changed over time.  I haven't found any good tools or frameworks to parse the XML and generate well typed data structures to store the content.

Comment: Thank you, I have done this in the past (inserted the XML directly and used XPATH) but in this case, I would much rather have the data in tables that I can use easier.

Comment: @Jason maybe this will help http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/GenerateSQLFromXML1.aspx similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496296/is-there-a-tool-to-generate-database-schema-from-xml-schema